# Position fixed div won't overflow viewport

Tags: css

If I have a position fixed div and I apply a left offset so that there isn't enough room for it to be fully displayed on the screen rather than the screen overflowing and causing a horizontal scroll bar the div just reduces in width instead.

I don't want the div width to change as this causes the items in it to wrap. I have found that I can get over this issue by setting an explicit width on the div but this isn't really a solution since the number of items each time is dynamic.

Is there a way so that if it won't fit on the screen it will just go off the side of the screen rather than resizing without setting a width?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3x6L4fw/)

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    left: 0px;
}
.tooltip .item {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {

        window_width = $(window).width();
        offset = window_width - 642 + 200;

        html = '<div class="tooltip">';
        html+= '<div class="item"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="" /></div>';
        html+= '<div class="item"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="" /></div>';
        html+= '<div class="item"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200" alt="" /></div>';
        html+= '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        html+= '</div>';

        $('body').append(html);

        $('.tooltip').css({left: offset })
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying display table to .tooltip seems to do the trick